Facial recognition computer vision image classification model with high accuracy (95%)/low validation (0%)
I have a Tensorflow Keras computer vision code training on 6120 images of 399 classes to identify individuals (ie facial recognition). The code runs through to the end (EarlyStopping) with the training accuracy increasing from 0/20/40/60/80% through the 1/3/5/7/9th epoch. However the validation accuracy remains at approx 0%, and at epoch 2/4/6/8 etc the training accuracy returns to 0%.
Running in Visual Studio Code (and Google Colab) a warning is given at the start of the second epoch:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/trainers/data_adapters/py_dataset_adapter.py:121: 
UserWarning: Your `PyDataset` class should call `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in its constructor. 
`**kwargs` can include `workers`, `use_multiprocessing`, `max_queue_size`. 
Do not pass these arguments to `fit()`, as they will be ignored.
  self._warn_if_super_not_called()

However, I believe this isn't required as I'm using ImageDataGenerator directly from Keras and not defining a custom class that inherits from a parent class?
After the second epoch I get the warning:
/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py:153: 
UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that 
your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches. 
You may need to use the `.repeat()` function when building your dataset.
  self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)"

I have code output:
Number of classes: 399
Training samples: 4896
Validation samples: 1224
Batch Size 32

So this should be OK?
The question is why is the accuracy flipping from 0 to up to 90%?
Why is the Validation accuracy always approx 0%?
The data set should be OK for individual identification and 'bad' images have been removed.
This is the code. (Note: To establish a baseline accuracy it doesn't contain multiple-folds, specific face recognition approach, data augmentation, or ensemble techniques - also run on CPU to simplify).
### Load the CSV file

data = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')

### Load & Prepare Data

data['image_id_index'] = data['image_id_index'].astype(str) + '.JPG'
data['person_id_index'] = data['person_id_index'].astype(str)

###  Separate Data for Testing & Validation

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,validation_split=0.2)

### Training data generator

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=data,directory='data/images',x_col='image_id_index',y_col='person_id_index',subset='training',batch_size=32,seed=42,shuffle=True,class_mode='categorical',target_size=(224, 224))

### Validation data generator 

validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=data,directory='data/images',x_col='image_id_index',y_col='person_id_index',subset='validation',batch_size=32,seed=42,shuffle=True,class_mode='categorical',target_size=(224, 224))

### Check if the generators are correctly initialized

print(f"Number of classes: {len(train_generator.class_indices)}")
print(f"Training samples: {train_generator.samples}")
print(f"Validation samples: {validation_generator.samples}")

### Get the number of classes

num_classes = len(train_generator.class_indices)

### Create Model

### Load the EfficientNetB0 model

base_model = EfficientNetB0(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

### Add custom layers on top of the base model

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

### Define the model

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

### Compile the model

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

### Save Best Model in Training Loop & Early Stop if Not Learning

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.keras', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')            
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', patience=10, verbose=1, mode='max')

### Train the model

history = model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size,validation_data=validation_generator,                                                                                      Train Modelvalidation_steps=validation_generator.samples // validation_generator.batch_size,epochs=50,callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stopping])

This is a sample of the output:
Found 4896 validated image filenames belonging to 399 classes.
Found 1224 validated image filenames belonging to 399 classes.
Number of classes: 399
Training samples: 4896
Validation samples: 1224
Epoch 1/50
c:\Users\DL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\trainers\data_adapters\py_dataset_adapter.py:121: UserWarning: Your `PyDataset` class should call `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in its constructor. `**kwargs` can include `workers`, `use_multiprocessing`, `max_queue_size`. Do not pass these arguments to `fit()`, as they will be ignored.
  self._warn_if_super_not_called()
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 5s/step - accuracy: 0.0477 - loss: 5.3771
Epoch 1: val_accuracy improved from -inf to 0.00000, saving model to best_model.keras
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 878s 5s/step - accuracy: 0.0479 - loss: 5.3738 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 15.8792
Epoch 2/50
c:\Users\DL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py:155: UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches. You may need to use the `.repeat()` function when building your dataset.
  self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)

Epoch 2: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1s 5ms/step - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 16.1315
Epoch 3/50
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 5s/step - accuracy: 0.3166 - loss: 2.9714
Epoch 3: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 871s 6s/step - accuracy: 0.3168 - loss: 2.9705 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 14.4282
Epoch 4/50

Epoch 4: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 2ms/step - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 13.6400
Epoch 5/50
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 5s/step - accuracy: 0.6370 - loss: 1.4069
Epoch 5: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 783s 5s/step - accuracy: 0.6370 - loss: 1.4067 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 12.8972
Epoch 6/50

Epoch 6: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 2ms/step - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 13.7836
Epoch 7/50
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0s 5s/step - accuracy: 0.8319 - loss: 0.6269
Epoch 7: val_accuracy did not improve from 0.00000
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 786s 5s/step - accuracy: 0.8318 - loss: 0.6270 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 16.8751
Epoch 8/50
...
153/153 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 771s 5s/step - accuracy: 0.9552 - loss: 0.1468 - val_accuracy: 0.0016 - val_loss: 21.7740
Epoch 21: early stopping
Training accuracy: 0.9552696347236633
Validation accuracy: 0.0016447368543595076

